# How to set interface settings for WINS using netsh?

Tags: windows, netsh, wins

On the Advanced settings in the of a network interface Properties there is the WINS tab, where  the address for the WINS server can be set.

[image: WINS Settings]

How do I add the address using `netsh` instead, for both interfaces with static addresses, and ones with addresses received through DHCP?

I've tried a few things which I thought would have worked, but they didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have an interface called "Local Area Connection 1" that you want DHCP to set WINS addresses for:

```
netsh interface ip set wins name="Local Area Connection 1" source=dhcp
```

Now, you might want "Local Area Connection 2" to have a static WINS source:

```
netsh interface ip set wins name="Local Area Connection 2" source=static addr=10.0.1.11
```

Check out the TechNet documentation for [`netsh interface ip`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738592(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: I've actually been trying `netsh int ipv4 set winsservers name=LAN source=dhcp` on a desktop machine, but nothing has appeared in the GUI, and nothing in `ipconfig /all`.  The command appears to be accepted, but with no effect.  Is a reboot needed?  The remove server with a static address which I need to do this on has no GUI, so I need to make sure this is correct before I try it on that, as I do not want to mess it up.

Comment: Okay, it seems that one need to use the second command on DHCP clients and the first command is actually meant for *WINS Servers* which have DHCP addresses.